# How to make two variables from one positional parameter?

Tags: shell, unix

I need to add two numbers to a positional argument $1 with a dash between them i.e. "15-20". It is an interval from 15 to 20 and it has to be a **one positional parameter**. I did this:

```
#!/bin/sh
a=$(echo "$1" | sed 's/-/ /g')
echo $a
```

It prints:
    *15 20*
I will need this in the future as an interval so I have to take each of these numbers as a seperate variables. Instead of a = 15 20, it should be a = 15 and b = 20. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why does it have to be one parameter?  You control the script, and you can re-structure the parameters as you wish.  Make the first line of your script `set ${@//-/ }` and all parameters that contain a hyphen will be split into two (or more) parameters.  Experiment with that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `bash` you can use process substitution:

```
read a b < <(echo "$1" | sed 's/-/ /g')

# and check values
declare -p a b
declare -- a="15"
declare -- b="20"
```

As the helpful comment from @chepner below, you don't even need `sed`. You can use read both variables using a custom `IFS`:

```
IFS=- read a b <<< "$1"
```

Answer (score 4):

With `/bin/sh`, use `read` and a here document.

```
IFS=- read a b <<EOF
$1
EOF
```

Or, use parameter expansion twice to drop the prefix/suffix.

```
a=${1%-*}
b=${1#*-}
```